# UISearchBar don't move up

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

```
//tableview
self.specialAttentionTableView = [[BATableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64 + searchBarH, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 50)];
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
self.specialAttentionTableView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.specialAttentionTableView];
//searchBar
_searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, self.view.frame.size.width, searchBarH)];
_searchBar.placeholder = @"Search";
_searchBar.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:_searchBar];
//searchDisplayController
_searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc]initWithSearchBar:_searchBar contentsController:self];
_searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
_searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
```

If I add `SearchBar` to `self.view`, the `SearchBar` won't move up to NavigationBar

However,if I add it to `tableView.headView`, it works
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhGO3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add this code:

```
_searchBar.bounds =  CGRectMake(0, 64, self.view.frame.size.width, searchBarH);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying to do here is add the Search bar into the Navigation Bar. Even I faced somewhat similar issue earlier and what I did is that I created a Custom View and included the Search Bar inside the Custom View and then add the Custom View to the Navigation Controller.
I think you might find the code below helpful.

```
[self.searchView addSubview:self.searchController.searchBar];

[self.navigationController.topViewController.view addSubview: self.searchView];
```